# What states is Kraken doing business in

Tags: exchanges, regulation

Is there a list of states that the [kraken](https://www.kraken.com/) exchange is currently doing business in?

Answer (score 1):

[Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/) also known as [Payward Ventures Inc](https://www.kraken.com/about/payward) is currently registered as a Money Service Business in [every single state in the US](http://www.fincen.gov/financial_institutions/msb/msbstateselector.html).

As far as I can tell however they will still not do business for the 2nd 3rd or 4th tier verifications in any state. I have no idea why this is.

[image]